# PHP asort by value ASC, value 0 should go last

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, php-7.4

I have the following array:

```
$values = [
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => 0,
  'd' => 3,
  'e' => 2
];
```

I need to be able to sort it like so:

```
$values = [
  'b' => 1,
  'e' => 2,
  'd' => 3,
  'a' => 0,
  'c' => 0
];
```

The fastest solution I managed to come up with is:

```
$zero = array_filter($values, fn($val) => $val === 0);

$non_zero = array_diff_assoc($values, $zero);
asort($non_zero);

$result = array_merge($non_zero, $zero);
```

Sorting rules:

- keys need to be preserved
- key order does not matter for the same value

My question is: is there a better way to do this?

[Here is a sandbox version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11e3aa197740cddfce61f1be18ea93ef1a584f02)

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

It looks like this one might work too:

```
asort($values);
uasort($values, function($a, $b){
    return $a === 0 ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[Sandbox for this version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/751f5684c41b8d4736aeb57eeec5a6285ecc1060)

Any better ideas?

Comment: Do you have to keep your indexes?

Comment: @CarlosCarucce yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with this solution which looks decent:

```
$values = [
  'i' => 2,
  'a' => 0,
  'b' => 1,
  'f' => 1,
  'c' => 0,
  'd' => 3,
  'g' => 3,
  'e' => 2,
  'h' => 3,
];

uasort($values, function($a, $b){
    if ($a === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    if ($b === 0 || $a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return $a < $b && $b !== 0 ? -1 : 1;
});
```

And it appears to be returning the expected output on all cases:

```
Array
(
    [b] => 1
    [f] => 1
    [i] => 2
    [e] => 2
    [d] => 3
    [g] => 3
    [h] => 3
    [c] => 0
    [a] => 0
)
```

Comment: If your array holds only integer values then this works fine. However, a value like 0.0 is going to be a disappointment. Probably a loosely comparison will do it for you.

Comment: @Rain I will never have negative values or 0.0 . It actually compares prices and puts the 0 ones at the end. The prices are float numbers and it seems to work correctly. Do you have any case, other than 0.0, which would make it fail?

Comment: Well, since prices are `float` then yes `(float)0` will fail too.

Comment: `(float)0` will never happen. Because of the way prices are calculated before the sorting needs to take place